# 1TB 2.5" in unibody macbook pro?

Tags: hard-drive, macbook

The 1 TB WD scorpio blue drive is a little bit thicker than ordinary 2.5" drives - does it fit inside the 2009 unibody macbook pro 13"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, that thing is a beast of a drive!

The scorpio is 12.5mm and has 3 platters inside, the unibody Macbook has a 9.5mm bay. I believe the 17" MacBook Pro can, but not the unibody models.

Answer (score 1):

It Fits in a 15" Unibody!!!  I've done it.  I'm running a scorpion blue in my 15" 2.6Mhz macbook pro unibody (all aluminum).  I was nervous at first but once installed the HD cover fits.  I've got 500GB of Snow Leopard and 500GB of Win7.  Only wish they made a 7200K RPM model.  5400K works OK, but I love the snappy response of a 7200K.